# DOCKER: cannot pull from my private registry

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I cannot use docker pull in my own registry, and I have a system like:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.5.1
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3
 Built:        Fri Sep 11 01:46:35 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3
 Built:        Thu Sep 10 19:10:10 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

and my os is OS X

```
Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

and the error message is like:

```
docker pull 192.168.5.46:5000/ubuntu:trusty
Error response from daemon: unable to ping registry endpoint https://192.168.5.46:5000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://192.168.5.46:5000/v2/: EOF
v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://192.168.5.46:5000/v1/_ping: EOF
```

and I use boot2docker, set set the env like:

```
env | grep DOCKER
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/Sirius/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
```

Hope for your help, thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some info about the registry config please?

Comment: nothing specific, all default

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `DOCKER_OPTS` into your env, this works well in Ubuntu OS.

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 192.168.5.46:5000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is install the crt in your client. When you setup your owner registry, you create the key/crt on the registry host.

```
mkdir -p certs && openssl req \
-newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout certs/domain.key \
-x509 -days 365 -out certs/domain.crt
```

And you start a container with registry image and the key/crt on the registry host.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name gcregistry \
-v /registry/data:/var/lib/registry \
-v /registry/certs:/certs \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
registry:2
```

To access the CA, install the crt on the client. The you can pull from the https

```
scp certs/domain.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/ghostcloud.cn:5000/ca.crt
restart docker
```